# Share PDF file on iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, nsdata

I Would like to know if i could use `UIActivityViewController` so i can share a PDF file by email, or message, or other means possible.

```
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkToProspect]];
```

This is my PDF data that i would like to share.

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:*NSARRAY* applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And this is the way i would like to do it.

Is there such a way ? Or should i create something custom ?

Comment: Did you try it? Does it do what you want?

Comment: The problem is that initWithActivityItems: expects a NSArray and if i create the array with pdf data inside, the app crashes.

Comment: "Instead of actual data objects, the objects in this array can be objects that adopt the UIActivityItemSource protocol, such as UIActivityItemProvider objects. Source and provider objects act as proxies for the corresponding data in situations where you do not want to provide that data until it is needed."

Comment: do that ;) write an item for your raw data

Comment: oh and then.. whats the activity?

Comment: FYI - you might actually want to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` instead of `UIActivityViewController`.

Answer (score 4):

```
// pathToPDF should be a full path to your PDF file
NSString *pathToPDF = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ReadMe" ofType:@"pdf"];  

NSURL *urlToPDF = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToPDF]; 

NSMutableArray *itemsToShare = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[itemsToShare addObject:urlToPDF];

UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```